# Pandas: converting date into usable format and counting period

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
           timestamp                   
0          09/May/2016:10:53:30  
1          09/May/2016:10:54:30  
2          09/May/2016:10:55:30             
3          09/May/2016:10:56:30
4          09/May/2016:10:57:30
5          09/May/2016:10:58:30
6          09/May/2016:10:59:30
```

Format is `day/month/year:hours:minutes:seconds`

I need to calculate a **two-minute** period for each timestamp. But the problem here is that date is in wrong format to be used with pandas `to_period` function. I have tried:

```
df['Period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.to_period(minute=2, errors='coerce')
```

But this throws exception:

```
Unknown string format
```

Expected output would be like:

```
           timestamp                         Period
0          09/May/2016:10:53:30                 1
1          09/May/2016:10:54:30                 1
2          09/May/2016:10:55:30                 1                 
3          09/May/2016:10:56:30                 2
4          09/May/2016:10:57:30                 2
5          09/May/2016:10:58:30                 2
6          09/May/2016:10:59:30                 3
```

Any advise would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can pass the `format` of `datetime` string while calling `pd.to_datetime` and also [to_period](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) doesn't seem to have minute parameter.

Comment: It's there for `Period`, not for `to_period` method

Comment: Yes, my bad. Could I use Period for this purpose?

Comment: Weird, it throws the very same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need can pass proper `formatting` to the `pd.to_datetime`

```py
    >>timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
    >>timestamp
    0   2016-05-09 10:53:30
    1   2016-05-09 10:54:30
    2   2016-05-09 10:55:30
    3   2016-05-09 10:56:30
    4   2016-05-09 10:57:30
    5   2016-05-09 10:58:30
    6   2016-05-09 10:59:30
    Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now, you can calculate the time elapsed since the first row, and get the time difference in seconds then divide by `120 (=2 Minutes)`, and then finally round it.
You will end up with something like

```py
    >>periods=((timestamp - timestamp.iloc[0]).dt.total_seconds()/120).round()
    >>periods
    0    0.0
    1    1.0
    2    1.0
    3    2.0
    4    2.0
    5    2.0
    6    3.0
    Name: timestamp, dtype: float64
```

You might have noticed that the very first value is 0.0, which is obvious, cause we are subtracting the same value for the first row, you can just replace this value by 1.
`periods.iloc[0] = 1`

So the final output becomes:

```py
    >>periods
    0    1.0
    1    1.0
    2    1.0
    3    2.0
    4    2.0
    5    2.0
    6    3.0
    Name: timestamp, dtype: float64
```

You can verify this method for some other data as well..

```py
>>timestamp
0   2016-05-09 10:53:30
1   2016-05-09 10:58:30
2   2016-05-09 10:59:30
3   2016-05-09 11:20:30
4   2016-05-09 11:25:30
5   2016-05-09 11:30:30
6   2016-05-09 11:31:30

periods=((timestamp - timestamp.iloc[0]).dt.total_seconds()/120).round()
periods.iloc[0] = 1
```

**Output**:

```py
>>periods
0     1.0
1     2.0
2     3.0
3    14.0
4    16.0
5    18.0
6    19.0
Name: timestamp, dtype: float64
```

Comment: good one. Just to add, maybe better to use `timestamp.min()` instead of `.iloc` because there's no guarantee the data is sorted

Comment: yeah, or just can create the masking for `periods=0`

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if I was enough clear. What I meant was when taking the diference from first date, it'll be safer to do it like `timestamp - timestamp.min()` instead of `timestamp - timestamp.iloc[0]`, as if the Series is not sorted,  `.iloc[0]` won't really be first date (in the sense of the earliest)

Comment: Oh yeah, I just assumed the data you provided.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the most simple way to achieve what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the date format you have. You may need to convert your month name to numbers e.g. May --> "05" an specify the format:

```py
date_format = "%d/%m/%Y:%H:%M:%S"
dict_months = {
    "January": "01",
    "February": "02",
    "March": "03",
    "April": "04",
    "May": "05",
    "June": "06",
    "July": "07",
    "August": "08",
    "September": "09",
    "October": "10",
    "November": "11",
    "December": "12"
}
```

This will make the error vanish ...

It is a little bit dirty, (and there might exist native pandas function to do it, ¯_(ツ)_/¯), but here's one solution to it:

```py
# define your start date and a period, and then after every period minutes increment the value of period like this
start_date = pd.to_datetime("09/05/2016:10:53:30", format=date_format)
period = 2
time_period_func = lambda x: int(1 + ((x - start_date).total_seconds()//60 ) // (period+1))

df["period"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"].replace(dict_months, regex=True), format=date_format).apply(time_period_func)
```

basically you get the timedelta in minutes between current date and start. Then you apply a simple formula to get the period by dividing timedelta bu period.

*Edit 1*:
My answer didn't take into account the seconds, only the minute parts of the timestamp!
If you want to consider the seconds too, then check @ThePyGuy 's answer which I think is the right way to go

Comment: This solves the first problem, how would I calculate period by two-minute frequency?